# How do I get git to use the cli rather than some GUI application when asking for GPG password?

Tags: git, gpg, gpg-agent

Whenever I try to create a signed git commit, I need to enter my GPG key. It spawns some GUI application to receive the password. It looked like the application was [`seahorse`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Seahorse), so I uninstalled it, but git still uses some GUI app. Polybar doesn't report the application name and it's title is just `[process]@MYPC`.

How do I get git to use the command line / pinentry?

Versions:

- [gnuPG](https://gnupg.org/): 2.2.19
- [git](https://git-scm.com/): 2.25.1
- [pinentry](https://gnupg.org/related_software/pinentry/): 1.1.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's in your `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`?

I have `pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses` in mine, and everything which uses `gpg` will ask for my pass-phrase in the terminal.

NOTE: You will need to restart your gpg-agent (or send it a HUP signal) if you change its config.  Just running `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` will do, `gpg` will restart it when needed.

ALSO NOTE: the environment variable GPG_TTY needs to be your **current** tty (i.e. the tty you're currently running `gpg` in - or whatever calls gpg, such as `mutt`, `pass`, `git`, etc).  So add the following to your ~/.bashrc (or whatever's appropriate for your shell):

```
GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export GPG_TTY
```

See `man gpg-agent` for details.

Answer (score 14):

This is a GnuPG configuration issue, not a git configuration issue.

You can force GnuPG to use a terminal-based dialog for entering your password by setting the `pinentry-program` in your `gpg-agent.conf`. For a simple terminal prompt, put the following in your `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`:

```
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-tty
```

For a curses-based prompt:

```
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses
```